# chartjs-plugin-zoom: get currently visible values when the page first loads

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a chart component called genStarts whose view depends on the visible data of the following chart (singleChart). I'm using the onZoomComplete and onPanComplete options to insert my getVisibleValues function so that genStarts can be updated on zooms and pans. However, I have no way to get the currently visible values when the page first starts up. My getVisibleValues function does not work outside of the chartStyle object, and I haven't found a chart option that executes on startup.

In other words, my genStarts graph is only populated when SingleChart is zoomed or panned but I want it to be populated immediately.

```
const SingleChart = React.memo(({ setVisible }) => {

  function getVisibleValues({ chart }) {
    setVisible(chart.scales.x.ticks);
  }
  const chartStyle = {
    options: {
      animation: false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        zoom: {
          zoom: {
            wheel: {
              enabled: true,
              modifierKey: "shift",
            },
            pinch: {
              enabled: true,
            },
            enabled: true,
            drag: true,
            mode: "x",
            onZoomComplete: getVisibleValues,
          },
          pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: "x",
            speed: 2,
            onPanComplete: getVisibleValues,
          },
          mode: "xy",
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
      },

      scales: {
        y: {
          type: "linear",
          display: "true",
          position: "left",
          grid: {
            drawBorder: true,
            color: "#000000",
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            color: "#000000",
          },
          title: {
            display: yAxisLabel != "",
            text: yAxisLabel,
          },
        },

        x: {
          max: 9,
          grid: {
            drawBorder: true,
            color: "#00000",
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
            color: "#000000",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

 // ... some code to get chartData

  return (
    <div>
      <Line
        data={chartData}
        options={chartStyle.options}
        width={20}
        height={195}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default SingleChart;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the animations, they have a property to check if its the first time they have fired, although since you dont want animations you will need to set the main one to a verry low number and at least the tooltip to false and the transition duration of active elements to 0.

```js
const getVisibleValues = ({
  chart
}) => {
  console.log(chart.scales.x.ticks.map(el => ({
    value: el.value,
    label: el.label
  }))) // Map because stack console prints whole circular context which takes long time
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      onComplete: (ani) => {
        if (ani.initial) {
          getVisibleValues(ani)
        }
      },
      duration: 0.0001
    },
    transitions: {
      active: {
        animation: {
          duration: 0
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        animation: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```